# How to Append/Add Data to an ASP.NET Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I have real time data coming from energy meters and I have to render this data to a table. I am a beginner and do not know how to append data to a `Session`. When I add data to the `Session` the old data gets lost.

```
public void Get_Real_Time_Values(Real_Time_Values values)
{
    //please any guidance for appending data
    Session["values"] = values;
}

if (datList.Count >= 100)
{
    datList.RemoveRange(1, 20);
}
```

Comment: You can store collection into `Session`. You can't just append with the same key, how you expect to get your values back if you use the same key? Just create some collection and whenever you want to append some data, just get that collection from `Session`, add your new data to that collection, then store that collection back to `Session`.

Comment: you probably need something like this `if(Session["values"]==null) { Session["values"] = new List<Real_Time_Values>() }; ((List<Real_Time_Values>)Session["values"]).Add(values);`

Answer (score 0):

the data in Session is identified with a key. You cannot simply append data to it, but what you can do is append data to it in an indirect manner:

How?

Well, first read the data from the session into an object, list of object whatever you have, then append your new data to it then store the data back in the session.

An example would look like this:

```
Real_Time_Values currentSessionData = (Real_Time_Values )Session["values"];

currentSessionData.Add(newData)

Session["values"] = currentSessionData;
```

Be careful with how much data you store in the session though. If you have too much data you might want to start using a database or some sort of caching layer.